# Query of current date in time mysql

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I have a column of time with type datetime in mysql called `createdAt`, so I want find out the data with time range like this

```
createdAt >= SUBDATE(DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK), WEEKDAY(curdate()))
       and createdAt <= ADDDATE(DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK), 6-WEEKDAY(curdate()))
```

assume `createdAt curdate()` based on this question made are october 8th 2020, so that time range will be  `28th september 2020 until 04th october 2020`

But when I check manually, if I add some time range in another media, why the counting is little bit more different? For example: using this query, count of transaction is 87 transaction, but then I used another media to count the transaction between 28th september 2020 00:00:00 until 04th october 23:59:59 its 90 transaction, is that any I can add in query for time range in my query date range?

Comment: Is it mean select records createdAt previous week?

Comment: yes i want to selected createdAt previous week, but i thought the data inside that time range will always be counted, so i thought from 28th september 00:00:00 until 04th october 23:59:59 is inside the data, but when i check it, it's not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expression `ADDDATE(DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK), 6-WEEKDAY(curdate()))` returns only date part of last week day, so all data after start this day is not included.

You have couple of options to solve this:

1. Round createdAt to date withot time part:

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE DATE(createdAt) BETWEEN 
    SUBDATE(DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK), WEEKDAY(curdate())) AND
    ADDDATE(DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK), 6-WEEKDAY(curdate()));
```

2. Use strong less condition with next day:

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE 
    createdAt >= SUBDATE(DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK), WEEKDAY(curdate())) AND
    createdAt < ADDDATE(DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK), 7-WEEKDAY(curdate()));
```