# Difference between using date(createdAt) and without createdAt

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a `createdAt` date column of type `datetime`.

Why is the result of this code snippet

```
DATE(om.createdAt) BETWEEN 
    DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)  AND
    ADDDATE(DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK), INTERVAL 6 DAY)
```

different than

```
om.createdAt BETWEEN 
    DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)  AND
    ADDDATE(DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK), INTERVAL 6 DAY)
```

and how to make this function time

```
 DATE(om.createdAt) BETWEEN 
        DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)  AND
        ADDDATE(DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK), INTERVAL 6 DAY)
```

run faster because in my database it takes for almost 4 seconds. instead of the 2nd function (without date) are just only 0,19 seconds.

Comment: Is this not duplicate of your previous question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64258445/query-of-current-date-in-time-mysql/64278044#64278044

Comment: nope, its asking why the 'same' function has a different results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first condition slow because it apply convert DATETIME to DATE fror each row in table, so it will be slow on big tables.
You can use next condition without type casting:

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table om
WHERE 
    om.createdAt >= DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)  AND
    om.createdAt < ADDDATE(DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK), INTERVAL 7 DAY);
```

For answer to your question why those conditions returns different results, I can provide next example:

```
is 3 <= round(4.2) <= 4 (true), but 3 <= 4.2 <= 4 (false)
```

and like your case you can solve the problem in next way:

```
 is 3 <= round(4.2) <= 4 (true), but 3 <= 4.2 < 5 (true)
```